# SQL query "Find the article that has generated most income?"

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a SQL query that shows me the article that generated most income. (in a shop)

```
    Table = orderrader

   rownumber    articlenumber   ordernumber price   amount
   1            11              1           8624    3
   2            6               1           4794    2
   3            17              1           8755    3
   4            1               1           7803    1
   5            16              1           8987    3
   6            10              1           4575    3
   7            4               1           8747    1
   8            15              1           5439    3
   9            11              2           8624    3
   10           1               2           7803    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following sql statement will return only one articlenumber with max revenue.

```
Select  articlenumber, sum(price*amount) as totalincome
from orderrader
group by articlenumber 
order by sum(price*amount) desc LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT articlenumber
FROM orderrader
WHERE (price * amount) = (SELECT MAX(price * amount) FROM orderrader)
```

This should do the trick, i checked it on my own database. It will give ONLY the one with the highest price*amount

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT articlenumber, SUM(price*amount) AS income
FROM table
GROUP BY articlenumber
ORDER BY income DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select articlenumber, sum(price*amount) as s from orderrader group by articlenumber order by s desc;
```

Comment: only one ariclenumber is required in result